# Create file from FileWriter method?

Tags: java, methods, filewriter

I have been attempting to create a file from an ArrayList of menus with the Java FileWriter method but for some reason it's not creating the new file. However, it is finding my data but not writing it into a line as well. Any suggestions?

```
public static void writeMenu(String fileName, ArrayList<Menu> menus) {
        try{
            //ArrayList<Menu> menu = new ArrayList<Menu>();
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("data/menus.txt");
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
                for(int i=0; i< menus.size(); i++){
                    Menu menu1 = menus.get(i);
                    bw.write(menu1.description());
                    bw.newLine();
                }
                System.out.println(bw);

            bw.close();
            fw.close();
        } catch(IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Comment: I see you send fileName arg but you did not use it, your code will create file called "data/menus.tx"

Comment: Yeah that was my mistake I switched it to fileName but for some reason the File is still not being created?

Comment: @AhmadAl-Kurdi Please try it why? It is most unusual to use absolute paths in applications.

Answer (score 0):

I checked your code (changing Menu class objects to String objects to simplify it) on my computer and almost everything seems to be fine.
I passed this: `writeMenu("src\\hello.txt", menus);` in the `main()` method and the file `hello.txt` has been created in `src` folder.

The main issue in your code seems to be that line:

```
 FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("data/menus.txt");
```

I think that your intention was to write code that creates a writer with the argument passed to method `writeMenu()`, so it should look like this:

```
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(fileName);
```

Also check if you place slash or backslash in the file path (in Windows you should put double backslash (`\\`) instead of slash (the first backslash is used to escape character).

I think that a good idea to help you understand how I changed it and checked it is to paste here working code:

```
import java.awt.Menu;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Test {

    public static void writeMenu(String fileName, ArrayList<String> menus) {
        try{
            //ArrayList<Menu> menu = new ArrayList<Menu>();
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(fileName);
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
                for(int i=0; i< menus.size(); i++){
                    String menu1 = menus.get(i);
                    bw.write(menu1);
                    bw.newLine();
                }
                System.out.println(bw);

            bw.close();
            fw.close();
        } catch(IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>((Arrays.asList("a b c d e f g".split(" "))));
        writeMenu("src\\hello.txt", strings);
    }
}
```

File `hello.txt` contains:

```
a
b
c
d
e
f
g
```

As you see, `writeMenu()` is in the same class as `main()` method in which I call it so I do not have to write `Test.writeMenu("src\\hello.txt", strings);`, `writeMenu("src\\hello.txt", strings);` is enough in that case. If your `writeMenu()` were in the body of another class, then you need to call it with the name of enclosing class, such as: `Outer.writeMenu()` (`Outer` is just an example of name of the class containing `writeMenu()` method to help you understand it).

Comment: Thanks I realized that and changed it! But should I be referencing the path in a certain way when implementing the method? Right now I have it referencing the class and implementing the method like this with where I want the file and what it should be called: FileManager.writeMenu("data/menus.txt", menuArray);

Comment: I edited and improved my answer to help you get it, I hope it helps you understand it.